# JPQL How to sum up a given property of children and fetch these children avoiding n + 1 selections?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, jpql

I have two entities: category and product. They are associated and category is a parent:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "categories")
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "inc")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "inc", strategy = "increment")
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int totalQuantity;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "category")
    private Set<Product> products;
  
    public Category(int id, String name, int totalQuantity, Set<Product> products) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.totalQuantity = totalQuantity;
        this.products = products;
    }
```

Product entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "inc")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "inc", strategy = "increment")
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int amount;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private Category category
}
```

(`totalQuantity` is the sum of the `amount` of products associated to the category )
I want to get all categories and all associated products in such a way as to prevent n + 1 and do a summation. This is my query that is wrong/uncompleted because I have no idea how I can do/complete it:

```
@Query("SELECT new com.example.demo.category.Category(p.category.id, p.category.name, SUM(p.amount), ) FROM Product p GROUP BY p.category.id")
List<Category> findAll();
```

EDIT:
To better show the goal, I add my category view ("Front", "Back-end") with products associated with each of them:
[image: Category view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `@Formula` keyword to do native sql to sum product amount.

```
// the p.category_id=id <-- this id is Category itself id
@Formula("(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(p.amount),0) FROM products p INNER JOIN categories c ON p.category_id=c.id WHERE p.category_id=id)")
private int totalQuantity;
```

> Note: If your totalQuantity type is int, you need to use `COALESCE` avoid the null value. If it type is Integer, you don't need to use it.

Use `LEFT JOIN FETCH` to prevent N+1 problem.

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT c FROM Category c LEFT JOIN FETCH c.products")
List<Category> findAll()
```

The Hibernate sql result:

```
select distinct category0_.id                         as id1_6_0_,
                products1_.id                         as id1_11_1_,
                category0_.name                       as name2_6_0_,
                (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(p.amount), 0)
                 FROM product p
                          INNER JOIN categories c ON p.category_id = c.id
                 where p.category_id = category0_.id) as formula1_0_,
                products1_.amount                     as amount2_11_1_,
                products1_.category_id                as category4_11_1_,
                products1_.name                       as name3_11_1_,
                products1_.category_id                as category4_11_0__,
                products1_.id                         as id1_11_0__
from categories category0_
         left outer join products products1_ on category0_.id = products1_.category_id
```

You can use one query to get all categories and sum amount of products in the same time.

---

#### Old answer

You can use the `LEFT JOIN FETCH` to prevent n+1 problem.

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT c FROM Category c LEFT JOIN FETCH c.products")
List<Category> findAll();
```

Use the `sum()` operator calculate product amount.

```
List<Category> categories = categoryRepository.findAll().stream().peek(category -> {
    Set<Product> products = category.getProducts();
    if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(products)) {
        int totalQuantity = products.stream().mapToInt(Product::getAmount).sum();
        category.setTotalQuantity(totalQuantity);
    }
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Finally, you can use one query to get all categories and count the total amount of products.

---

Comment: Isn't it possible to build this query to also do summation inside the query?

Comment: @Monoxyd I update the answer. You can build this query and do summation inside the query.

Comment: It looks fine, but I get this error when I add the @Formula keyword: `org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet`

Comment: MySQL, my db name is `shop-db` . `SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
2021-07-02 17:33:30.944 ERROR 7492 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : (conn=330) Table 'shop-db.product' doesn't exist
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause`

Comment: I am confused why there is `shop-db.product` instead of `shop-db.products` ( table `products` exists in my db)

Comment: It's seems missing the product table. Sorry I forget to your table name is products not product and is categories not category. Update answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have a project with this feature, you can create a entity like this

[SampleEntity](https://github.com/lukkascost/Experiments_IA_Data/blob/7678d051f1981101ec5b7d523a892d86cc5b2525/commons.module/src/main/java/br/com/lukkascost/commons/module/models/entities/SampleEntity.java#L20)

```java
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "sample")
    private Set<AttributeEntity> attributes = new HashSet<>();
```

With a list of an entity. Create a DTO with a field with a long term like

[SampleDTO](https://github.com/lukkascost/Experiments_IA_Data/blob/7678d051f1981101ec5b7d523a892d86cc5b2525/commons.module/src/main/java/br/com/lukkascost/commons/module/models/dto/SampleDTO.java#L11)

And when you cast the entity to DTO object you can use the count, in my case I`ve used the mapStruct plugin

[SampleMapper](https://github.com/lukkascost/Experiments_IA_Data/blob/develop/commons.module/src/main/java/br/com/lukkascost/commons/module/mappers/SampleModelMapper.java)

```java
    public abstract List<SampleDTO> convert(List<SampleEntity> sampleEntities);

    public long map(Set<AttributeEntity> past) {
        return past.size();
    }
```

In my service I call find all

```java
@Override
    public List<SampleDTO> findAll() {
        List<SampleEntity> entities = sampleRepository.findAll();
        return sampleMapper.convert(entities);
    }
```

and the repository is default for jpaRepository

```java
public interface ISampleRepository extends JpaRepository<SampleEntity, UUID> , JpaSpecificationExecutor<SampleEntity> {

}
```